# Where should I load data from user defaults?

Tags: ios, swift

My app implements a navigation bar: it has a main view and a setting view. In the setting view, I save some user's preferences by using UserDefaults. Then when I go back to the main view, the new preferences do not appear. It only appears after I reopen the app. I load the user defaults values in the ViewController's viewDidLoad method. It looks like that viewDidLoad method would not be called again after going back from setting view to the main view. So where should I load the data from user defaults instead?

Here is how I load the preferences:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    numberOfPeople = defaults.double(forKey: "numberOfPeopleDefault")
    tipPercentage = defaults.double(forKey: "tipPercentageDefault") / 100.0
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use UserDefaults to pass data between view controllers

Comment: He is talking about "settings", he probably needs to store those variables in same place, might be a cache, or whatever. The point is, since `viewDidLoad` is called just once, "refreshing" of the `previous` view controller cannot be done there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you might move your variables inside `viewWillAppear` (called every time `ViewController` appears), eg:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)

  numberOfPeople = defaults.double(forKey: "numberOfPeopleDefault")
  tipPercentage = defaults.double(forKey: "tipPercentageDefault") / 100.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find some value in using didSet for your variables. Here's an example you might find useful.

```
class vc: UIViewController {
  var numpplLabel: UILabel!
  var tipLabel: UILabel!

  var numberOfPeople: Double = 0 {
    didSet {
      guard oldValue != numberOfPeople else { return }
      numpplLabel.text = "\(numberOfPeople) ppl"
    }
  }

  var tipPercentage: Double = 0.2 {
    didSet {
      guard oldValue != tipPercentage else { return }
      tipLabel.text = "\(tip)% tip"
    }
  }

  var tip: Double { return tipPercentage*100 }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    numberOfPeople = defaults.double(forKey: "numberOfPeopleDefault")
    tipPercentage = defaults.double(forKey: "tipPercentageDefault")
  }
}
```